# Python generated *.msg file

Tags: python

I'm Jan and it's my first post here and the following code is also my first python code. So please don't judge me, if the code is not well shaped :) and don't wonder I had to reduce my mail body.

With the following code I try to generate several msg file depending on a user list called "customer_names". The idea is to iterate through this list and to adjust the email body espacially the placeholder for "Customer". The rest of the body content is not so important. Everything works good except the iteration through the list. I have a suggestion that I may need to increment the index for the list in the loop. Do you have any ideas.

```
import win32com.client as win32
import datetime
import random

# List of customer names
customer_names = ['Name1','Name2','Name3']
current_customer_index = 0

# List of email providers
email_providers = ['provider1', 'provider2', 'provider3']


# set up the Outlook application
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')

# create a new email
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

# set the subject and recipients
mail.Subject = "Request for Customer Information"
mail.To = "user@emailprovider.net"


# Message body for the email
message = f"Dear User,\n\nThe information we require from [Customer] is as follows:\n\n- Email Address: [Email Address] \n\nWe kindly request that you send the requested information to us within [number of days] days. \n\n Kind regards."

# set the number of days for the customer to respond
num_days = 7

# set the importance of the email to normal
mail.Importance = 1  # 0=Low, 1=Normal, 2=High

# set the sensitivity of the email to normal
mail.Sensitivity = 0  # 0=Normal, 1=Personal, 2=Private, 3=Confidential

# set the read receipt option to true
mail.ReadReceiptRequested = True

# add a reminder for the sender to follow up in 3 days
mail.FlagRequest = "Follow up"
mail.FlagDueBy = (datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=3)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

# Generate a random email
for i in range(len(customer_names)):
    customer = customer_names[i]
    message_with_data = message.replace("[Customer]", customer)
    message_with_data = message_with_data.replace("[number of days]", str(num_days))
  
    mail.Body = message_with_data
    file_name = "Request_" + customer + ".msg"
    file_path = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/Email/" + file_name
    mail.SaveAs(file_path)
```

Comment: What results are you seeing? e.g. How many messages (if any) are being saved to your desktop?

Comment: If there are any error messages from your code, please include them here. Not including the errors you receive is a common new user issue, but it is easily correctable.

Comment: This code generate 3 mails according to the amount of users. That's ok. But the have the same content:

Dear User, 
The information we require from Name1 is as follows: 
- Email Address: [Email Address] 
We kindly request that you send the requested information to us within [number of days] days.
Kind regards.


For the first the user name "Name1" it is correct, but for the second mail, "Name1" should replaced by "Name2" (third mail with "Name3")

The code seems correct, I do not receive error messages.